# Why can't I browse the internet while using my mouse?

Tags: mouse, samsung-galaxy-j7

I recently got a Galaxy J7 (2017), and it's running Android 7.0. I chose a Galaxy because I can plug a mouse directly into the phone. I can't access the device otherwise.

Everything was working great for the first few days, but then last night I began experiencing trouble browsing the internet. Instead of being able to click and scroll through a website, it's as though the arrow became a text cursor. Each time I attempt to scroll I am only able to highlight the text on the screen.

It looks like this: 
[image]

Any ideas what's going on here and how it can be resolved? I'd really appreciate your feedback. Thanks!

UPDATE: After several factory resets, I think I've identified the problem. The system is preloaded with internet browser 6.2. This version works fine. After about a day, the internet browser updates to version 7.2. This is when the problem occurs. I have turned off automatic updates in Google Play, but it still updates on its own. I'm assuming because its part of the system. Nevertheless, I'm stuck yet again.

Comment: Does this only happen in the browser, or in other apps too? Try the Gmail app, and look at a document in Google Docs.

Comment: @DanHulme - It happens in other apps too. I am able to navigate around the inbox of the Gmail app, but once I open an email, I can't scroll down the message; it just highlights the text as if I were in a word processor. It seems like this started after I copy/pasted some phone numbers while adding new contacts. I have cleared the clipboard, but the problem remains.

Comment: It's ages since I've used a mouse with Android. It could be that this is a deliberate feature because you would use a scroll wheel instead of dragging. After all, this is how a mouse behaves on a PC.

Comment: @DanHulme - That could be, but it worked as a drag and scroll for the first few days. Makes me think I unknowingly changed a setting.

Comment: @DanHulme and beeshyams I've updated the original post with additional information. The problem seems to be related to the latest version of the internet browser. Is there a way I can prevent it from upgrading?

Comment: You can factory reset again, switch off the internet, and force stop, disable the app from settings and activate internet. This may stop auto updating

Comment: @beeshyams This is my first time working with Android. Can you point me in the direction of a tutorial that outlines what you just described?

Comment: See this https://android.stackexchange.com/a/75885/131553